# XMLHttpRequest cannot load and Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Tags: angularjs, ajax, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework and angularjs I use chrome for viewing my logs but here i am doing a login page I am trying to post the user entered data to serve but i am getting this error like .

```
 OPTIONS http://aflaree.com/qrcodeservice/Service1.svc/login
```

and this one is next error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load  http://aflaree.com/qrcodeservice/Service1.svc/login Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405`
   after reading some blog i figure there is a CORS extention from from which allows ajax request i tried that also but i am not able to find why this two error is appearing. here is my code

https://plnkr.co/edit/Dz0aFsLqoQcnCxht00z3?p=preview

my code work fine in device but I am getting error in chrome if any one knows why please help me

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the fix please?

Comment: this is issues is solved by my back end this error occurs because of back end does not provide me the **access controll allow orgin** or you can say it as they did not provided me permissions. i dont know about back end .

Comment: I had set access control allow origin * in backend but still i get same issue

Answer (score 17, accepted):

CORS actually specifies that two requests should be made to the server on an AJAX call (if certain conditions apply, like sending custom headers).

The first request (the one with the `OPTIONS` method) is called pre-flight and is used to check if it's safe to send the full request to the server. The response from the server should contain a valid `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header containing the URL of the client or `*`.

Your server (and not the client) is the one that needs to support CORS. It seems you are using .Net for it, so you may want to take a look [here](http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html) on how configure IIS.

You can read more about CORS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: thanks for your answer yorch i have the the data in web.config file but still i am faceing the same issues

Comment: I added the configuration part to the web.config but still can fix the error

Comment: What if someones has to hit 3rd party API ?

Comment: @yorch I have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` set on my IIS server. Then also I am getting the error. Do you think setting `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS` will be required as well.
I am getting 405(Method Not Allowed) along with preflight error.

Comment: @yorch: I've used as specified details , its giving me error always

Answer (score 13):

If you're using chrome, get "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin" plugin. This will let you ignore all CORS errors.

It works on mobile because ionic has a cordova plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist". In your "config.xml" you'll see the line  by default, that means your app can access any URL.

Unfortunately when testing through the browser the cordova plugin is not active.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS devices, also check the protocol used. Using HTTPS instead of HTTP solved the issue for me.