# AngularJS & Node.js CORS not working for PUT/POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have a CORS problem with my app.

My stack is Node.js with Express 4 and AngularJS

I already have tried a few things but I keep getting for all POST/PUT requests:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

In the server side I have enabled CORS using the npm `cors` module

```
var cors = require('cors');
var corsOptions = {
  origin: [
    'http://www.localhost:5555',
    'http://www.somedomain.com'
  ],
  methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
  allowedHeaders: [
    'Content-Type',
    'Content-Length',
    'Content-Range',
    'Content-Disposition',
    'Content-Description',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Authorization',
    'Origin',
    'X-Requested-With',
    'X-AUTH-TOKEN'
  ],
  credentials: true
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

In the AngularJS part I am using this:

```
// App Config
App.config(['$httpProvider',
  function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  }
]);

// Request in the Angular service
var deferred = $q.defer();
var host = 'http://www.localhost:5555';
var id = 'some-id';
var data = {};

$http.put(host + '/roles/' + id, data).
  success(function (data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  }).
  error(function (err) {
    deferred.reject(err);
  });

return deferred.promise;
```

The GET requests work fine. The PUT/POST requests keep returning the same error above. The preflight OPTIONS is successful however.

Thanks

Comment: are you running your angular app in localhost? if you are, you should add "http : // localhost" to your origin option into the corsOption object.

Comment: you probably need to create a proxy http://shawnsimondeveloper.com/nodeproxyangular/

Comment: please check this stack overflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002979/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-and-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-co/36003110#36003110

Comment: @PabloMáximo I'm running the app on localhost for development, but also on a domain in production. both urls are in the list of origins (updated question). I'm particularly interested in finding out why the GET requests work but not the PUT/POST

Comment: Can you update the question adding the code where you make the POST/PUT request?

Comment: Showing the code which actually handles the PUT/POST request would be useful too.

Comment: Why have you put `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the allowed headers? They are response headers and have no business being on the request in the first place.

Comment: @PabloMáximo updated the question showing the code that makes the request from Angular.

Comment: @Quentin the code that handles the request on the backend, actually forwards the request to another underlying backend service like so

function (req, res) {
    var url = 'some-url';
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
  }

Not sure if that makes any difference though

Comment: In the angularJS part, is the request requested **from** http://www.localhost:5555?

Answer (score -2):

This works for me with CORs in an Express 4 server

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, POST, GET, PUT, DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", YOUR HEADERS HERE);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
      return res.sendStatus(200);
  } else {
      next();
  }
});
```

Comment: Why should that fix the problem? What's wrong with the existing code?