# $http.get() Error ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have to work with the API rest but i have this error every time whenever do?

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

```
$scope.submit = function(login, password){
url = 'http://x.x.x.x:x/x/x/x/x/'+login+'?password='+password;
console.log(url);
instanceId = '1';
tokenId = '';
userId = '';
$http.get(url, {
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Context': 'instance='+tokenId+';token='+tokenId+';user='+userId
      }
  })
  .success(function(data){
    $scope.firstName = data.user.firstName;
    $scope.lastName = data.user.lastName;
    $scope.profession = data.user.mission;

    userId = data.user.id;*/
    localStorage.setItem("userId", JSON.stringify(userId));
    $location.path('app/home/');
  })
  .error(function(data, status){
    console.log(data + "-" + status);
    alert(status);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002979/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-and-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-co

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is only an issue when running your app in development mode with `ionic serve` or `ionic run/emulate -l`, and not when running as a mobile app packaged with Cordova, a simple option is to just disable CORS altogether for local development. If you use `Chrome` for debugging, there's a plugin called [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) that lets you disable CORS.
Or if you want to solve this issue, there has two ways:

- The first, and easier, solution is to just allow all origins from your API endpoint. The disadvantage is that we can not always control the endpoint we are accessing.
- Fortunately, we have second way: `Ionic CLI proxy server`, ionic has supplied an awesome blog about this, please refer to http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/.

Hope this will help, regard.