# Cors request Rejected

Tags: ionic-framework

I am facing an error and I don't known what to do. Whenever I try to save user to my ionic user service using the following code:

```js
Ionic.io();
var user = Ionic.User.current();
if (user.id) {
  user.set('name', username);
  //user.set('image',image_name);
}
user.save();
```

and then I get this error:

> Ionic User: Error: CORS request rejected
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.ionic.io/auth/users/null.
>   Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404
>   OPTIONS https:// api .ionic .io /auth /users /null
>   [cors request rejected][1]
>   [coding][2]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002979/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-and-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-co

Answer (score 1):

Ionic has a cordova plugin that sorts out all CORS issues called "cordova-plugin-whitelist". When you test through the browser, the Cordova plugins are not active, hence it's not sorting out your issues. Only when you deploy your app to android/ios/windows will the Cordova plugins work.

Rather get "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin" chrome plugin to allow you to make requests if you want to test on your browser.

Comment: ok. do you known how can about this url https://api.ionic.io/auth/users/null is NULL @TheAppchemist

Comment: i have installed the Allow-Control-Allow-Origin plugin to my chrome but still getting the error, what to do Please?