# Node-Express-CORS issue

Tags: node.js, express, cors, ionic2

**Ionic 2**

I am using login provider but when i set the access control to

`res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`

It is **not working**

But it works properly when i use

`res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8100');`

It is **working**

but now i want to deploy my app up on phone device i need to set it to wild card `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`. since my app on phone not working on `http://localhost:8100` anymore

**Anyone can help me solve this problem ?**

Comment: may be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002979/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-and-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-co

Answer (score 2):

If you are making a [preflighted request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) then the wildcard is forbidden in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

You can read the `Origin` request header in order to find out the origin. Then you can test it against a list of allowed origins (you could also assume that any origin is OK, but for a preflighted request there is a good chance that complete public access would be a security risk). Finally you can copy it into the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

Answer (score -1):

How is your HTTP request from your app looks like?

Look for "Types of CORS requests" in this [article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server).

If your HTTP request is a simple one, i.e.

- Method is `HEAD`, `GET`, or `POST`
- Only have these headers

  - `Accept`
  - `Accept-Language`
  - `Content-Language`
  - `Last-Event-ID`
  - `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-url-encoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain`

If your HTTP request is a simple one, preflight is not needed. And `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with `*` is accepted by the mobile app.

Otherwise, a preflight request will be made (i.e. `OPTION` request) and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` of `*` will be ignored. It must be fully specified like `http://localhost:8100`.

Comment: I found the problem, it because I used `withCredentials: true` inside request. It turns to preflight request. So I can not use `*`.  I want to use session store some auth data. if I test on device, It wont work `http://localhost:8100`, How can I solve with this problem ?