# Handle status (e.g. 503) in Axios OPTIONS response

Tags: javascript, http, vue.js, http-headers, axios

**edit2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37784969/107282 suggests that I needn't worry because it doesn't happen when on a real device.**

---

I'm using Axios in a VueJS hybrid (Cordova) app and am calling an API.

Axios is (correctly) doing a 'preflight' `OPTIONS` request before my `GET`/`POST` requests, but if the API returns a `503` at *that* point, my error handling code doesn't get called.

```js
HTTP.post(url, data, {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token.getAccessToken()}})
  .then(response => response)
  .catch(error => {
    // Not reached
  });
```

How do I catch this error status?

---

**edit**: screenshot from chrome dev tools:

[image: 503 on OPTIONS request]

Comment: What is the content of  `response` in case of `503`? Is `response.data` set?

Comment: I use axios and get 503 error handled by catch block on get operation, status is in error.response.status

Comment: Isn't 503 a network error? Network errors aren't handled by axios.

Comment: @Sergio I don't need any content when there's a 503, just to know that a 503 has occurred when it has done the preflight OPTIONS request.

Comment: @FAjir If I get the 503 in the POST/GET stage then yes, me too, but this is in the preflight OPTIONS request.

Comment: @sandrooco Network errors should cause a failed promise, but don't seem to when it happens in the OPTIONS request.

Comment: Network errors aren't handled by axios anyway.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of my question.

Comment: @jezmck, I believe the preflight OPTIONS request is sent by browser and not by your code, so I assume it cannot be handled by something which didn't even initiate it?

Comment: Seems plausible, though surely in that case, axios still fails somehow. I might not be able to get the status code, but some kind of failure notification? Anyway to confirm your suggestion?

Comment: What API are you calling?

Comment: It's my own, running Laravel. When it's in Maintenance mode, it returns a 503 for all requests (including OPTIONS requests).

Comment: FYI: I just quickly tested this by setting up Fiddler to respond with 503 to any OPTIONS requests and was still able to catch the error with `axios`. What browser / axios version are you using?

Answer (score 8):

I was able to reproduce the issue and the simplest fix I could find as below

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(null, (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

As you can see in my tests I was able to get the error for and response for different scenarios

[image: Network error]

Comment: That's not on the OPTIONS request though.

Comment: That's because you don't send the options requests

Answer (score 3):

Axios' `Network Error` isn't much descriptive. To rethrow it in a better way, we can do something like this, to at least describe what request got the error, and what happened:

```
instance.interceptors.response.use(null, error => {
  if (error && error.message === 'Network Error') {
    throw new Error(`Potential network CORS preflight error at ${error.config.url}`);
  }
  throw error;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Who want know what type of http status is response with axios interceptor that is a example

```
    axios.interceptors.response.use(function (res) {
        return res;
      },
      (err) => {
        if(err.response.status == 403 || err.response.status == 503) {
            //handle error of type
            obj[err.response.status] ? obj[err.response.status]() : obj["default"]();
        }
        return Promise.reject(err);
      });
```

You can made a map with status callback for diferent behaviours.

```
const obj = {
    503 : () => console.log("Forbidden"),
    417 : () => console.log("is a teepot"),
    'default': () => console.log("Not handle it")
}
```