# showing 400 (Bad Request) in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

I am using cordova and while doing json i am getting an error ***["Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdWWO.png)***".

[image]

But the same code when I run it on postman is getting the right answer.Please help me to solve this problem.
The code is:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  async: false,
  ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: jData,
  dataType: "json",

  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response)

  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {


  },

});
```

And a screenshot of the right answer on the postman is also given for your reference

Comment: _"**the server** responded with a status of 400 (**Bad Request**)"_ -> Check the request and what the server expects

Comment: 400 error means some parameters are missing.

Comment: then something is wrong with your jData json or api might expect different contenttype

Comment: but when I run the same url in the postman ,the right answer is getting

Answer (score 2):

you need to stringify the JSON data was sending

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  async: false,
  data: JSON.stringify(jData),
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response)

  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {


  }
});
```

Comment: after stringifying the json data, it shows the following errors:

Comment: 1.Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed  )

Comment: 2.Failed to load url :Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Comment: Maybe something missing in your server configuration tries to configure `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.[may this help][1].[may this help][2]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002979/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-and-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-co
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258959/cors-enabled-but-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-404-when-po

Comment: The problem was with the webservice.It was solved.The code is now working. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the open and closing brackets around your jData

var jData = {};

Not

var jData = [{}];